# The simplest review audit...

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review-audit

I just passed a review audit. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/240016).

As you can hopefully see from the link, I was one of those who voted to close the original question about two weeks ago. This smells like a bug to me...

Comment: I highly doubt that this is a bug. The review audits are mainly intended to trip up (and identify) the laziest of robo-reviewers (of whatever stripe). These are the sorts of reviewers that would have decided between "close" and "leave open" long before reading enough of a question to recognise that it _was_ one they had previously interacted with.

Comment: It's testing your memory. That's all...

Comment: $-1$ to express disagreement, simply for the reason that I don't want review audits getting any "harder."  Some of the "closing" audits are tough enough as it is... :)  But, $+1$ for noticing something is "off," so net $0$.

Comment: I have this happen routinely as well.

Comment: Dots, I see dots...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Audits are not supposed to be exhaustive.

They are there to catch out robo-reviewers, people who just go quickly through the review queue without actually looking at the content (so usually either approve everything or reject everything).

That you are paying enough attention to note this is a good sign.

Comment: Although I understand this, I do still think it is odd and should not happen. Similarly, I find it odd when I am asked of I want to close a question I have answered - I am clearly biased! (I try to skip contentious examples of these biased circumstances.)

Comment: I appreciate it feels strange, but again, the purpose of the audit is to ensure one is paying attention, not to provide a "perfect", undetectable, audit.

Comment: Sorry, the latter example it wasn't meant as an example of something odd in an audit, but rather something odd when reviewing.

Comment: @user1729 Now that you know that the current behavior is by design, if you think it should be changed, that should be a feature request. (So, a different post). A feature request is expected to explain what problem is created by the current behavior, and how the changed will be beneficial.

Comment: @900sit-upsaday I know what a feature request is! I was just trying to make polite conversation...

Comment: Also, @900sit-upsaday, you should edit your name to be "900 sit-[ups a day see](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/ups-a-daisy.html)".